# Lose Internet after my computer goes to sleep

Tags: laptop, suspend, suspend-resume

I have an HP TX2 laptop and am using Ubuntu 10.04 with the 2.6.34 kernel. When I close the lid of my computer, put it to sleep, and then open it later, I've lost the ability to connect to the Internet. There's an ethernet cable plugged in by the network manager can no longer find it. I have no choice but to reboot.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the chipset of your network card.  I know that some cards use firmware and need their state restored/reset.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your ethernet driver does not work after suspending your machine. You can tell Ubuntu to unload it before suspend and load it again after resuming your computer. To do so, you must create a file **/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules** and put in it the next entry:

**SUSPEND_MODULES="your_module_name_here"**

where **your_module_name_here** must be the name of the driver. You can find it using network manager.

Hope it helps

Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the cause, but a possible solution is manually forcing it.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
```

This COULD work, but it's obviously just a stop gap for figuring out the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ACPI issue.  On my own laptop a simple case of unplugging and replugging the network cable solves the issue.

Are you using Linux drivers or Windows drivers through NDISWrapper?

Comment: I am using Linux and have a Broadcom B43 wireless card, though that shouldn't matter because it doesn't get ethernet either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created the /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules file and entered the line:

SUSPEND_MODULES="r8169"

Do I have the name right? I took the name of the driver.
Should there be quotes?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This isn't really an answer... this should have been a comment on the original post, or an edit to it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue.

The command `lsmod` can be used to see all the loaded modules. Type the command in the terminal.

```
lsmod
```

Use the above command, when your wireless card is working otherwise you will not get the wireless driver name in the list.

When you have found the name of the driver module use that in `/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules`:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="your_module_name_here"
```

In my case it was `"ath9k"` This is the driver for Atheros Wireless driver. I simply used google to find further information about this driver.

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="ath9k"
```