# Ubuntu 22.04.3 in-tree driver rtw89_8852be wifi adapter "Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible" after sleep

Tags: drivers, suspend, pcie

I'm struggling with a network adapter that refuses to wake up after sleep/suspend. I found several posts and proposed solutions that didn't work, however most referred to the driver on lwfinger's github before official support from the new release 22.04.3LTS.

*The offending card is:* Realtek rtw89_8852be 
*My laptop:* HP 250 15.6 inch G10 Notebook 
*OS:* Dual Boot Windows 11 (preinstalled) and Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS (Luks encrypted)

The Wifi works without problems on Windows 11. A reboot reliably fixes the issues, until the next time the lid is closed.

### What I tried

- Removing and inserting back the driver via `modprobe`
- Stopping and starting the Networkmanager via `systemctl start NetworkManager`
- Disabling fast startup on Windows
- Making sure BIOS is on the newest available version (it was, F.06)
- Installing lwfinger's version of the driver
- Using lwfinger's patch script for suspend, which turns out uses `modprobe`before and after sleep
- Checked if PCI settings exist in the BIOS, tried to find the Advanced BIOS settings, but failed to do so
- `/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules` as described in [Lose Internet after my computer goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12177/lose-internet-after-my-computer-goes-to-sleep)
- Creating a configuration file as described here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286109

With none of these methods was I ever able to wake up the 'lost' network adapter.

### Sources

- lwfinger's driver on github: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89
- The installation guide I followed to have dual boot and encryption: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html
- Suspend modules answer mentioned above: [Lose Internet after my computer goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12177/lose-internet-after-my-computer-goes-to-sleepubuntu)
- Via a configuration file: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286109

This list is not complete as I did not note carefully enough all my trials, sorry.

### Command outputs that may be helpful

Because I tried many things and probably changed some things I shouldn't have, I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS to generate the following.

- `uname -a`

```
Linux loxo-HP-250-15-6-inch-G10-Notebook-PC 6.2.0-32-generic #32~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 18 10:40:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- `dmesg | grep -i rtw`

```
    [   10.066636] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
    [   10.071755] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 0.27.32.1, cmd version 0, type 1
    [   10.071761] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 0.27.32.1, cmd version 0, type 3
    [   10.376860] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: chip rfe_type is 41
    [   10.408225] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
    [   60.045410] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
    [   60.990803] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.061090] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.061104] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   61.134263] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.205184] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.205204] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   61.277505] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.348219] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   61.348223] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   71.496225] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   71.566623] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   71.566630] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   71.636713] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   71.706989] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   71.706996] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   82.439138] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   82.509862] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   82.509879] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   82.580557] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   82.650661] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   82.650675] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   93.421444] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   93.491571] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   93.491584] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [   93.562412] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   93.632540] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [   93.632553] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [  104.422774] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  104.493574] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  104.493588] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [  104.564459] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  104.634632] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  104.634648] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [  115.412278] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  115.483239] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  115.483257] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
    [  115.554159] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  115.625141] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
    [  115.625158] rtw89_8852be 0000:01:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
```

- `lsmod | grep -i 8852

```
rtw89_8852be           16384  0
rtw89_8852b           385024  1 rtw89_8852be
rtw89_pci              73728  1 rtw89_8852be
rtw89_core            561152  2 rtw89_8852b,rtw89_pci
cfg80211             1241088  3 rtw89_8852b,rtw89_core,mac80211
```

- `modinfo rtw89_8852be`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/rtw89_8852be.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Realtek 802.11ax wireless 8852BE driver
author:         Realtek Corporation
srcversion:     87FC3D1B28540DD0400027C
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B85Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B852sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtw89_pci,rtw89_8852b
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtw89_8852be
vermagic:       6.2.0-32-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        44:BA:4E:7F:5F:16:6D:D7:06:BE:07:56:BD:C2:3D:18:A6:4B:39:D3
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      7F:CC:4A:EA:C3:E6:21:83:F3:2A:BC:40:9F:6E:0D:95:BC:04:AF:29:
        E7:8B:C5:AD:AE:F8:B6:E5:D6:AD:8E:CC:70:73:9B:72:B2:C2:47:B5:
        D4:B6:1C:73:A0:B7:2C:36:1C:A9:FA:BE:B3:3F:94:22:59:93:33:DB:
        04:A2:E9:DC:9E:7F:B8:E0:A3:57:95:F6:D3:C2:F5:F3:2C:45:18:1F:
        57:3E:0F:D2:76:BB:9A:DA:73:57:0D:D8:4F:42:35:EF:A1:10:7D:F3:
        F2:15:F3:91:AE:EC:5F:95:0D:10:AB:89:CA:20:D6:65:54:9C:46:B6:
        8A:02:CC:20:1A:52:64:4F:62:CD:D2:8A:9F:D3:6C:9F:03:2A:BD:7E:
        A7:CF:FD:93:F0:52:5F:B4:05:AB:BE:52:24:6F:C3:9B:90:34:23:CD:
        59:84:AA:B7:BC:98:E0:38:9E:F1:24:46:8F:9F:D2:A7:23:01:60:A8:
        36:7A:E8:E4:E2:A7:4E:1B:99:DC:52:94:83:EA:51:5A:19:9E:B9:0D:
        A0:B5:14:93:6F:33:AA:89:22:AF:AF:44:D3:67:2C:54:68:A5:42:8F:
        39:81:3C:0D:B5:06:BE:DF:F7:15:C8:62:0E:70:75:92:17:5B:D7:7F:
        51:D7:8B:FD:EC:99:F9:6D:0F:E1:59:21:F7:3B:D4:41:F6:C6:1D:3C:
        EA:2D:40:28:A8:ED:6E:C8:85:45:F4:B6:AF:A3:EE:07:D1:88:C7:9C:
        A6:08:13:9B:E9:D0:0B:11:FB:9B:27:DD:81:43:27:B8:1B:92:D5:3B:
        FD:E6:03:F2:89:6E:F6:42:7B:27:AF:E5:EB:8C:14:B3:6A:53:4A:A1:
        82:11:02:2B:CC:A8:08:9B:56:CC:E9:62:E9:B8:E9:83:1E:E9:9F:43:
        FA:32:85:1D:28:D2:82:8C:8A:8B:3D:C7:B6:4A:0C:7D:56:AE:19:B6:
        86:DD:C5:F7:9F:92:8B:8F:3C:66:66:CA:D3:05:0B:B3:E8:91:9C:86:
        A8:24:B3:BF:FA:15:9D:F6:52:EB:40:8F:5F:29:97:7F:F2:76:E0:73:
        FF:FB:5E:70:1A:1F:AD:D5:AF:83:18:46:82:10:03:DD:F8:6D:03:38:
        1B:A7:90:51:93:24:14:97:07:6D:FA:77:E4:25:0B:49:4D:62:96:F8:
        31:73:36:FA:E5:BD:1F:1E:5D:8B:CD:82:78:01:72:8F:1E:DE:02:E4:
        E2:E9:76:4E:CC:BE:80:99:3C:47:E0:56:C0:6E:F1:1E:B4:24:E3:11:
        E0:CA:48:D0:5F:2A:6D:10:99:A1:64:87:3D:76:BF:2A:27:00:F9:3D:
        FD:D6:0B:2F:0D:7B:0F:B3:B6:0B:7C:63
```

- `lspci -v` after a sleep / loss of network adapter, section of network controller only

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b85b (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be
```

- `lspci -v` before sleep / working network adapter, section of network controller only

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b85b
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88e6
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at 80500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be
```

Please ask for any additional command output or info that I can provide. Many thanks for any suggestions, I am out of ideas for this one.

Comment: As a workaround, is there maybe a way to prevent the network adapter from entering D3cold state in the first place?

Comment: I've had similar issues with several WiFi adapters over the years, I've always chosen preventing the device from sleeping as a solution.